# How to give "admin" role access to all pages in .net core web project?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I have a .net core/5 razor pages project.

I'm using Authorize tags and Policy requirements to restrict access to pages. I would like to ensure that Admin has access to all pages by default without needing to add that to every policy or on every page using Authorize(Roles = "Admin").

```
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
o.AddPolicy("AtLeastStore", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new StoreOrGreaterRequirement()));
o.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
.Build();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Authorize tags and Policy requirements to restrict access to
> pages. I would like to ensure that Admin has access to all pages by
> default without needing to add that to every policy or on every page
> using Authorize(Roles = "Admin").

You could set the Razor Pages authorization conventions, put the admin related page in an admin folder, then, use the following AuthorizePage convention to add an AuthorizeFilter to the page at the specified path:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    // specify an authorization policy for the admin folder.
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/admin", "AtLeast21");

    //Besides, you can also use the AuthorizePage method to specify an authorization policy for the admin related pages.
    //specify an authorization policy for the page.
    //options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Contact", "AtLeast21");
});
```

More detail information, see [AuthorizePage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pageconventioncollectionextensions.authorizepage?view=aspnetcore-5.0), [AuthorizeFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pageconventioncollectionextensions.authorizefolder?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [Razor Pages authorization conventions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: This does not answer my question. This is just a way to add a policy to either a folder or a page.

I want to add admin Role as the default to bypass all authentication. Meaning if a user has Admin he/she doesn’t need any other roles to access a page that might be secured by a policy or role.

Comment: Hi @Canolyb1, From your previous reply, I thought you have already configured your application to achieve the [Role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0#policy-based-role-checks) (create a Policy to check a user's role, then based on it to do the authentication), so I suggested you add the policy to the folder or the page. you could consider use this method.

Comment: Here are some related articles about creating Policy-Based And Role-Based Authorization, you could refer to them: [Role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0#policy-based-role-checks) and [Policy-Based And Role-Based Authorization In ASP.NET Core 3.0 Using Custom Handler](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/policy-based-role-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/).